# TFS - Workspace to build definition with only required files

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

In our project we are building project with TFS build definition feature.In TFS build definition there is one option like "workspace" where we mention all require folders which contains file which used to build project successfully. We have separate folders as per requirements which contain different units. this units are in large numbers hence when we build project and mention any folder in workspace then it extract all files in that particular folder. actually we require only few of them for project build because we used different files per project but that files under same roof.

could any one help us that how we build our project with only require files in workspace rather than whole folder?

Comment: Workspaces are defined on folder level, there is no option to define just files. You could create a subfolder for each project and move the related files in there. Is there any reason why you mixed up the files from different projects? Is it to time/space consuming that you want to define it in such a detailed way?

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but We have lots of files in 3-4 folders and its not possible to rearrange them in sub folders, we have more than 140 exes which used files from 3-4 folders. i mean some common files are in 3-4 folders. when we give reference of whole folder, tfs auto build retrieve all files from that folder but we need only required files and its not possible to change references in all 140+ application by rearranging files in sub folder. Thanks for your suggestions but we need solutions for files

Answer (score 1):

Status =Active Source control folder =$/Artiion/ADO/LibForms/Loginf.pas: Build agent Folder=$(SourceDir)\LibForms\Loginf.pas

above example works fine

Answer (score 0):

There is no reasonable way to do this.  When you tell TFS Build what source folders to use, that is what you are telling it: get these folders.  In theory I suppose you could modify or write your own process template and provide custom fields in which you could provide data to the build process about what files you need for that build, and then create some custom action to call out that would then replace the standard TFS Get function in the process template.  But what would be the purpose?  If you have certain files that are to be included in the solution build, then simply have separate solutions or projects which would include the appropriate files.  Then build the specific solution based on which subcomponents you need, and then only those files will be built and copied to the drop location.  Sure, they would still have been retrieved in the build agent's workspace, but they would not have been used in the actual build or placed in the drop location.  If that's not good enough, and you need to actually Get different groups of files per build, then you should rearrange your files so that the necessary files are in the appropriate subfolders.

Comment: We have lots of files in 3-4 folders and its not possible to rearrange them in sub folders, we have more than 140 exes which used files from 3-4 folders. i mean some common files are in  3-4 folders. when we give reference of whole folder, tfs auto build retrieve all files from that folder but we need only required files and its not possible to change references in all 140+ application by rearranging files in sub folder.  Thanks for your suggestions but we need solutions for files

Comment: In that case I would first point out that the answer above is still the correct answer, as far as I know.  TFS build does not provide the capability to Get specific files, so if this is truly a requirement (which I am still a bit skeptical about) then you would need to write your own build process template including the TFS Get functions to return specific files provided as arguments.  At that point you might be better off going with a different build tool like Jenkins or TeamCity which may (or may not) provide more specific filters for what to get from version control.